# Fill NAs forwards or backwards if values in other columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, fillna

Given this example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["20180724", "20180725", "20180731", "20180723", "20180731"],
    "identity": [None, "A123456789", None, None, None],
    "hid": [12345, 12345, 12345, 54321, 54321],
    "hospital": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "result": [70, None, 100, 90, 78]
})
```

Because the first three rows have the same `hid` and `hospital`, the values in `identity` should also be identical. As for the other two rows, they have the same `hid` and `hospital` as well, but no known `identity` was provided, so the values in `identity` should remain missing. In other words, the desired output is:

```
       date    identity    hid hospital  result
0  20180724  A123456789  12345        A    70.0
1  20180725  A123456789  12345        A     NaN
2  20180731  A123456789  12345        A   100.0
3  20180723        None  54321        B    90.0
4  20180731        None  54321        B    78.0
```

I can loop through all combinations of `hid`s and `hospital`s like `for hid, hospital in df[["hid", "hospital"]].drop_duplicates().itertuples(index=False)`, but I don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `apply` in combination with `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
df['identity'] = df.groupby(['hid', 'hospital'])['identity'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

This will fill NaNs forward *and* backwards while separating the values for the specified groups.

Comment: It really seems like my question was not complete enough to replicate my problem. I am sorry for that. Would you mind looking at my edits and see if your answer changes?

Comment: @ytu: No problems. I adjusted the answer, see if it works for you.